# How to do row level operation and append to existing DataFrame in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like:

```
      a     b     c     d
0     1     2     3     4
1     4     7     2     8
2     5     7     6     9
```

I want to make a new dataframe like

```
      a     b     c     d  sum multiply
0     1     2     3     4  10   24
1     4     7     2     8  21   448
2     5     7     6     9  27   1890
```

Where sum=a+b+c+d
and
multiply=a*b*c*d

Comment: `df['sum'] = df.sum(1). Same for `prod`

Comment: `sum`: `df.sum(axis=1)` , `multiply`: `df.prod(1)`

Comment: I also have sqrt dividend in the calculation while I receive     91             return converter(self.iloc[0])
     92         raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to "
---> 93                         "{0}".format(str(converter))) error

Answer (score 0):

```
df['sum'] = df['a']+df['b']+df['c']+df['d']
df['multiply'] = df['a']*df['b']*df['c']*df['d']
```